# how do you extract from a string that contains "\" in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to extract `MHadi` from the string `Corp\MHadi`.
I use the following code, but I get an error each time.

```
$MyUser = "Corp\Mhadi";
$MyName = explode("\", $MyUser);
echo "Actual User = $MyUser <br />";
echo "First part = $MyName [0]<br />";
echo "Second part = $MyName [1]<br />";
```

Comment: `\ ` is the escape character, you need to escape it again like `"\\"` or else php thinks you are trying to escape the quote.

Comment: @Machavity Yes you can. Numeric arrays there is no issue, assoc arrays you need to wrap in curly braces or leave off the quotes around the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"\" escapes a character. just do

```
$MyName = explode("\\",$MyUser);
```

it should work

```
$MyUser = "Corp\Mhadi";
$MyName = explode("\\", $MyUser);
echo "Actual User = ".$MyUser." <br />";
echo "First part = ".$MyName[0]."<br />";
echo "Second part = ".$MyName[1]."<br />";
```

Comment: `Corp\Mhadi` should also likely be `\\ `

Comment: Corp\Mhadi is alright. when exploding, just add two backslashes. it applies only to backslashes since it is an escape character.

so if the string were to be $var = "Corp/Mhadi" , mind the forward slash, you could do explode('/', $var);

Comment: afaik, `\M` isn't a character that needs escaping, I was just suggesting it because it might be, similar to `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the `\` as that is the escape-character in php.

```
$MyUser = "Corp\Mhadi";
echo "Actual User = $MyUser <br />";
$MyName = explode('\\', $MyUser);
echo "First part = $MyName[0]<br />";
echo "Second part = $MyName[1]<br />";
```

That way it will work.